# How to decode a huffman coding without the prefix property

Tags: huffman-code, fax

I'm trying to decode a buffer encoded with [Modified Huffman Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Huffman_coding).

Here's the beginning of the buffer: `000111100001111011111010001000011101000011101000011110`

From looking at the [translation table](https://web.archive.org/web/20020628195336/http://www.netnam.vn/unescocourse/computervision/104.htm), it looks like the prefix property required for Modified Huffman isn't guaranteed. According to the table, I see that `00011` signifies `7B`, but `000111` signifies `1W`. In this case, how do I decode the buffer above? Am I reading the table wrong or is there some nuance to the algorithm that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified Huffman Coding assumes you start with a run of white pixels, as noted in the translation table in your link. If it doesn't, the code for a run of "0" white pixels is used.

```
00110101 = 0W
000111   = 1W
and so on...
```

In your example you start with 1W `000111` then 3B `10` and so on...

As John has pointed out, your translation table is wrong. 
The correct table can be found here: [Correct Modified Huffman Coding Translation Table](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0471221538.appd)

Comment: You cannot have 0W followed by 1W. The encoding always alternates between White and Black pixels.

Comment: The 0W and 1W are from the translation table, copied from the white column - not from the sequence.

Comment: There are still multiple faulty prefix properties, e.g. 13W `000011` is a prefix of 37W `00001110`.

Comment: In the case of 13W vs 37W you need to see what comes after, if the next code is white, you know that it is 13W 3B and not 37W, if the next one is black, you know that it is 37W. Remember this is always alternating between white and black termination codes unless you stumble onto a makeup code - then the next code is a termination code that should be added to the makeup code.

Comment: @Espen, I don't think what you are saying is correct. How would he know where the current `000011*` code ends to figure out that the next is going to be Black or White? The codebook table in the link the OP posted is simply wrong. `37W` should be `00010110`.

Comment: You are correct John, my mistake. Been a while since I did this. But I do remember we read each line before doing parsing because of the makeup codes.

Comment: The correct tables can be found here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0471221538.appd

Answer (score 2):

Modified Huffman Coding uses an alternating encoding of White and Black pixels. The encoding always starts with a White pixel. So, in your example, the buffer decodes to `000111=1W`, `10=3B`, `000111=1W`, and so on.